# Android/iOSでmp3をコピーガードしたい

Tags: android, ios, objective-c, java, unity3d

お世話になっております。お知恵をお貸しください。
Unityにて開発中ですが
Android/iOSにて、
①パスワード付きzipにしたmp3ファイルをAudioClip等で再生する方法
②byte[]にしたmp3をAudioClip等で再生する（zipアーカイブからwwwで読み込んでbyte[]になった）方法
または
③mp3ファイルをコピーガードする方法
いずれの一つでも方法が解るとありがたいです。
java,Objective-Cなどをプラグイン呼び出しでも、どんな方法でも可能性があればお知恵をお借りしたいです。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 2):

> ③mp3ファイルをコピーガードする方法

どの程度の保護レベルを求められているかによりますが、技術的に実現可能なベストのものということであれば、MicrosoftのPlayReadyなどのDRMテクノロジーを利用した方がよいと思います。

Answer (score 1):

私の知るかぎり、mp3である限り完璧なコピーガードは不可能です。  
zipパスワードは解読されたら終わりですし。  
(旧型PC1台での総当り方式でも8文字程度までのパスワードなら数時間で解読可能だったりします)

mp3のデータがクライアントにダウンロードできている時点で  
コピーも再生もできる状態になっているわけです。

そのためにコーデック自体にセキュリティ(DRM)を埋め込んだ方式が世の中に出回っています。  
コピーガードが必要であれば、目的のセキュリティが付与できる形式に  
エンコードしなおして配信することをおすすめします。

無理にでもmp3にこだわるのであれば独自にDRMを追加して暗号化したmp3形式を創りだしてしまうことですね。  
mp3とは呼べないかもしれませんが解読されない限りは圧縮も再生も自作の専用の物でしかできなくなりますよ